# Query of five fields using ArcPy in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am using a long script for doing this query using select by attribute:
this is the following code: are there any shorter form to do this?:

```
level1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
level2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
level3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
level4 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
level5 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
# field's names: L1_NAM,L2_NAM,L3_NAM,L4_NAM,L5_NAM,
query1 = "L1_NAM = '" + level1 + "'"
query2 = "L2_NAM = '" + level2 + "'"
query3 = "L3_NAM = '" + level3 + "'"
query4 = "L4_NAM = '" + level4 + "'"
query5 = "L5_NAM = '" + level5 + "'"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "NEW_SELECTION",  query1 )
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "SUBSET_SELECTION",  query2 )
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "SUBSET_SELECTION",  query3 )
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "SUBSET_SELECTION",  query4 )
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "SUBSET_SELECTION",  query5 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shorter form for doing this would be as below.  It uses Python string formatting to build a single expression from the five already built.

```
level1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
level2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
level3 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
level4 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
level5 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
# field's names: L1_NAM,L2_NAM,L3_NAM,L4_NAM,L5_NAM,
query1 = "L1_NAM = '" + level1 + "'"
query2 = "L2_NAM = '" + level2 + "'"
query3 = "L3_NAM = '" + level3 + "'"
query4 = "L4_NAM = '" + level4 + "'"
query5 = "L5_NAM = '" + level5 + "'"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer,"NEW_SELECTION", "{0} AND {1} AND {2} AND {3} AND {4}".format(query1,query2,query3,query4,query5))
```

Comment: If the queries were an array, you could use `" OR ".join(list)` as the where_clause.